# How to force a line break in chat conversation?

Tags: css, html, word-wrap

[PROBLEM SOLVED !!!!!!]

The **word-wrap: break-word** property actually is working with me.
The problem previously cause me no working is that I defined a **white-space: nowrap** property in  tag, so it conflicts with each other.

That's why !!

Thanks to everyone who viewed this post!!

**word-wrap: break-word**  ROCKS!

---

I have a chat conversation made of a div tag, and long words fall off the chat window

I googled solutions for a bit, and the **word-wrap: break-word;** property doesn't help.
I also tried **overflow-wrap: break-word;** and **word-break:break-word;**

I don't know what's wrong with my chat conversation div.

This is css of my chat conversation div:

```
.chatboxcontent {
 height: 180px;
 padding: 7px;
 width: 226px;
 overflow: auto;
 line-height: 1.3em;
 background-color: rgba(24, 175, 223, 0.25);
     word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

This is my chat conversation html tag:

```
<div class="chatboxcontent">
  I want to put my conversation here. 
the content is generated by javascript dynamically.
</div>
```

Here's the code where I generate the conversation (might be the part that goes wrong???)

```
if(event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey == 0)  {

    var $message = $(chatboxtextarea).val();
    $message = $message.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");

    $(chatboxtextarea).val('');
    $(chatboxtextarea).focus();
    $(chatboxtextarea).css('height','20px');
    if ($message != '') {

        $("#chatbox_"+name +" .chatboxcontent").append(myDate());
        $("#chatbox_"+name +" .chatboxcontent").append(username+': ');
        $("#chatbox_"+name +" .chatboxcontent").append($message);
        $("#chatbox_"+name +" .chatboxcontent").append("<br/>");

        // post content to server   
        $.post("sidechat/chat.php", {'from':username, 'to':indentedName, 'content':$message}, 
            function(data){
            //success function
            console.log("send message to db");
        });
    }

    return false;
}
```

My problem is long words still fall off the chat window as if the word-wrap property doesn't do anything.

need help.

thank you

Updated------07/16/13----------------

Here's the link to jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/f62N9/

It seems working fine on jsFiddle, but why it does nothing on my localhost ???

Comment: Please can you supply a fiddle

Comment: Where is the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/2uYYa/

Comment: You need to replicate the problem in a fiddle

Comment: I'm pretty sure `word-wrap` is helping you. See the difference here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cCItv . But it won't cut a word if there's room for it on next line.

Comment: Let me post the image of my chat box. It doesn't line break, and I don't know why. [image](http://goo.gl/BHKE7)

Comment: heres another image that show no effect of word-wrap, i don't know why. [image](http://goo.gl/xsJgS).  :(

Comment: try my chatbox, if you type long word, it won't break.
[web](http://68.181.15.18/fb%20chat/).

Comment: Post a jsFiddle of your problem.